# How to loop through an array of objects in a Svelte template?

Tags: loops, svelte

How do we pass an array to a Svelte template and loop over the contents?

My main.js looks like:

```
import App from './App.html';

const app = new App({
  target: document.body,
  data: [{name: 'hello'}, { name: 'world'}]
});

export default app;
```

My App.html file looks like:

```
{#each cats as cat}
    <h1>Hello {cat.name}!</h1>
{/each}

<style>
    h1 {
        color: purple;
    }
</style>
```

This seems like it should work.. but nothing appears. I've tried double curly braces as well for the each template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `data` should be an object that *contains* an array, it can't just be an array. So for that template, this:

```js
import App from './App.html';

const app = new App({
  target: document.body,
  data: {
    cats: [{name: 'hello'}, { name: 'world'}]
  }
});
```